# Beautiful Soup Neglecting Important Content on Webpage

Tags: python, html, parsing, css-selectors, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup to parse this [library hour page](https://hours.library.columbia.edu). Since the weather is bad today, the webpage shows an alert message to all students. The HTML code that contains the alert message is as follows:

```
<div id="alert-container">
  <div class="alert alert-error">
    <p>The University will resume normal operations on Wednesday, March 15.&nbsp; All Library facilities will be open according to the Spring Break 
schedule. &nbsp;
    <a href="http://hours.cul.columbia.edu/">Library Hours »
    </a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<!--
<div class="alert alert-error" style="margin-bottom:15px;text align:center;">
 <a href="http://library.columbia.edu/news/alert.html">Normal operations are expected to resume Monday, January 25. &nbsp; More information &raquo</a>
</div>
-->
```

I want to parse this alert message, but it turns out that no matter I use `lxml` or `html5lib`, it gives me the wrong parsing result:

```
<div id="alert-container">
</div>
  <!--
<div class="alert alert-error" style="margin-bottom:15px;text-align:center;">\
  <a href="http://library.columbia.edu/news/alert.html">Normal operations are expected to resume Monday, January 25. &nbsp; More information &raquo
  </a>
</div>
-->
```

That is to say, it removes all the content in `<div id="alert-container"></div>`, which seems very strange to me. I have parsed some websites, this is the first time I encounter this problem, and I think I follow the correct way to parse the website:

```
import urllib2
import html5lib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://hours.library.columbia.edu"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml') #or html5lib
soup.find("div", {"id":"alert-container"})
```

and the result of running the code above is:

```
<div id="alert-container"></div>
```

I'm wondering if this is the problem of the website itself or because of the parser?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The web site may use ajax for getting data. But urllib2.urlopen returns static pages. So how about using Phantom JS? It executes js in web site. And get page after ajax.

Comment: @ikicha Thank you so much! `PhantomJS` is such a useful tool, I'll learn to use it!

Comment: if you are new in js, casperjs is one of alternatives

Comment: @ikicha Yes, I am learning JS recently, thanks for your advice!!

Answer (score 1):

It is because the initial page does not have any elements in "alert-container" at first, but requests those elements through an Ajax request ("https://api.library.columbia.edu/query.json?qt=alerts"), which returns a string as the json format.

This code should work.

```
import urllib2
import json

url = "https://api.library.columbia.edu/query.json?qt=alerts"
alert = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
print(alert)
print(alert["alerts"][0]["html"])
```

Comment: It works, thank you! I didn't know Ajax before, I'll learn it now!